# How to allow the user edit a specific image's attributes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

so I have these user-generated pages that contain images that belong_to each page. I want to make edit buttons for each of these images that contain the image_id so that the website knows which image data to modify. How can I make it so that when the user clicks the edit button of a image, it pops up with a form that already knows it's modifying that specific image and its attributes in the database?

The form looks like this:

```
  <%= form_for @image do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>

  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>

  <%= f.submit %>
```

But it doesn't know which image to modify. Is there a way to make it so that when you click the edit button for a specific image, a form would pop up allowing you to edit that image's title and description? Hope that was clear, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since `@page` has_many `:images` you could generate edit links by

```
<% @page.images.each do |image| %>
   <%= link_to 'edit', edit_image_path(image) %>
<% end %>
```

a click on one of this links directs you to something like `/images/:id/edit` with the image.id in :id

you can also create input fields for each image:

```
<%= form_for @page do |f| %>
  <% @page.images.each do |image| %>
    <%= f.fields_for image do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

see [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)

Comment: this looks promising, i'll look into it. any way to have that link have a class of "edit-button" (using bootstrap)?

Comment: adding a class is easy: `link_to 'edit', edit_image_path(image), class: 'edit_button'`

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are using `form_for @image`, your form already knows the exact object which you are about to edit. There should be no need to explicitly specify a `photo_id` anywhere in the form. Just make sure that you have `title` and `description` fields in photos table.

Edit: Rendering Multiple Images

```
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
<%= form_for photo ... %>
.....Your code ......
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Even though there are a bunch of images on that one page?